# dlang: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

Tags: d

I'm trying to compile a simple hello world using dmd, but I get the following output:

```
dmd hi
/usr/bin/ld: hi.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
hi.o: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
--- errorlevel 1
```

So I try with -fPIC then

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/libphobos2.a(object_a_66e.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `_D12TypeInfo_Aya6__initZ' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/lib/libphobos2.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
--- errorlevel 1
```

This was a non-existent problem a month or so ago.

System: Arch Linux 64bit.

What could possibly be the problem?

```
dmd -m32 hi
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libphobos2.a when searching for -l:libphobos2.a
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libphobos2.a when searching for -l:libphobos2.a
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.2.0/../../../../lib/libphobos2.a when searching for -l:libphobos2.a
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.2.0/../../../../lib/libphobos2.a when searching for -l:libphobos2.a
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /lib/../lib/libphobos2.a when searching for -l:libphobos2.a
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /lib/../lib/libphobos2.a when searching for -l:libphobos2.a
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/../lib/libphobos2.a when searching for -l:libphobos2.a
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/../lib/libphobos2.a when searching for -l:libphobos2.a
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.2.0/../../../libphobos2.a when searching for -l:libphobos2.a
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.2.0/../../../libphobos2.a when searching for -l:libphobos2.a
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libphobos2.a when searching for -l:libphobos2.a
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libphobos2.a when searching for -l:libphobos2.a
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l:libphobos2.a
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libpthread.so when searching for -lpthread
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libpthread.a when searching for -lpthread
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
--- errorlevel 1
```

Comment: try both `dmd -m32 hi` and `dmd -m64 hi` and see if either of them do anything diferent.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why this error was occurring is because of the existence of the hardening-wrapper by https://github.com/thestinger/hardening-wrapper. The removal of this package solved the problem.